# Django Extend Content perserving old Get Results

Tags: python, django

I am proficient with python but quite new to django and html.
What is the best method to include additional data while keeping data that was previously queried for displayed on the same page?

Some of the sql data involves large datasets being manipulated in python, so I would rather not recalculate everything for a new view, when I am only intending to reuse the old view with 1 extra method/query. Thanks for the help.

This is a very stripped down template for exampleurl/experiment1/ to illustrate my problem.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load poll_extras %}
{% block content %}
{% block info %} #(loaded on default) {% endblock %}
{% block chart %} #(loaded with default values) {% endblock %}
{% block addinfo1 %}
    <select class="selectpicker" data-style="btn-info" onchange="if (this.value) window.location.href = this.value" method="get">
    <option value="?addinfo1=X">additional data X</option>
    <option value="?addinfo1=Y">addtional data Y</option>
    #(etc.) 
    </select> 
    {{if addinfo1}}     #(nothing loaded by default)
    #(display table) 
    {% endblock %}
{% block addinfo 2 %}
             <form class="addinfo search" action="/search/" role="search" method="get">
              <div class="form-group">
               <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name=q>
              </div>
              </form>
 {{if search_results }} #(nothing loaded by default) 
 {% endblock %}
{% endblock %}
```

I.e. Someone loads experiment 1, selects addinfo=X and then searches in the additional addinfo2 field - what is the best way to preserve the already loaded experiment1 and addinfo1 data while displaying new responses to his query (it really needs to work both ways though, that someone could get addinfo2 data and then change the addinfo1 from =x to =y without removing the addinfo2 data either) ?

Comment: What kind of method you want to apply in the old value?

Comment: I didn't understand.. so in the template context you have a variable, and you want to apply a method on this variable if needed in the template ?

Comment: So i have for example url(r'^experiment/(\S*)/$', experimentInfo) and def experimentInfo(request, experiment=None, addinfo1=None) - so if an experiment is specified it loads the default data, otherwise it renders base.html, if addInfo1 is passed in the GetRequest it's loading the default experiment data and the Get request data (but this already seems like redundant processing) - now I want to add another search function to show an additional datafield, while keeping all the data that's already been loaded on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:**

Based on the question you want to do this:

Show the page with one or more forms. When a form is submitted keep the old GET data displayed as it was.

**The answer is AJAX**

You create the form with an id, then you create a `view` with a unique url. send the GET data using AJAX to the url and when the result back you process it and show it in the same page.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" id="queryHolder">
<input type="button" id="mySearchButton">

<div id="searchResults">

</div>



<!-- make sure you included jQuery library -->

<script>

    $("#mySearchButton").click(function(){
        var query = $("#queryHolder").val();
        $.get("/search/", {q: query}, function(data){
            // the data came from the Django view.
            $("#searchResults").html(data)
        })
    })

</script>
```

When the search button clicked jQuery will send an Ajax request which will never reload the page. the GET request will be sent to `/search/` with 1 parameter called `q` which is equal to the input value.

When the data returned from the search view as an `HttpResponse()` you can use it if it's JSON or display it if it's pure HTML

Fact:

- You don't need a form if you don't need an action to be triggered.

Comment: But if I pass a Get Request to my view function with ?addinfo1=X?addinfo1=Y ?search=Z won't it requery all of those from the database, rather than just the last addition ?

Comment: 1. You can't send the same GET variable twice. 2. You will need to prepare the data in the view. I didn't fully understand your point here sorry, I need more explanation

Comment: If a page was loaded like so {{ if addinfo2 }} {% include "addInfo2.html %} and a get request is submitted for addInfo2 - can I check in real time and have it reverify the {{ if addinfo2 }} without calling and requerying the database for the view data on the entire page?

Comment: so what do you mean is submitting the GET request without reloading the page, so the view doesn't access the database and reload the entire page right?

Comment: I want to access the database *only* for the new GET request (and keep the old GET data displayed as it was) - is this possible?

Comment: So what you're saying is I can have a Django view that's always used only to receive an AJAX Query and then pass the data back for Display on the page?

Comment: Yes, this view will be the ajaxSearchView(request, query) will access the database and return the result to the AJAX request. when Ajax receive it you can display it in a div. IF you want more control or you want to keep you code clean in the view you can return JSON array and then play with it. The good thing is that AJAX will send the GET request in the background, so the page won't reload, just the content change!